# Puppeteer click() on selectors that keep changing - using regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, css-selectors, puppeteer

Using Puppeteer, `click("selector_here")` method will click on a selector. But the selector keeps changing values!

For example, one time it will be "#search-keyword-**901131292**" then it will change to something like "#search-keyword-**123891237**". It's a random number.

**Can I use a regex or something to select selectors that contain "#search-keyword-"?**

I've tried:

- `page.click("#search-keyword-*")`
- `page.click("\b#search-keyword-\b")`
- `page.click("/#search-keyword-/")`
- `page.click("#search-keyword-".includes())`

Answer (score 0):

This may be inefficient. But another option you have is select all elements with the same tag. Assume it is a  you can select all elements that are div. The run sometbing like element.attr("class").indexOf(//class name//) != -1